# Django M2M field unit-tests not failing

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have a model `Notification`

```
class Notification:
  reports = ManytoManyField()
```

On my code I had this line:

```
Notification.objects.create(reports=reports_list)
```

The above throws a database constraint violation when run (relating to report fk), although, when executing the same code with unittests, there is no error. I even assert the result and it passes, e.g:

```
notification = Notification.objects.create(reports=reports_list)
...
notification.refresh_from_db()
self.assertEqual(notification.reports.count(), 10)
```

Is this the expected behaviour on this scenario ?

Comment: `(relating to report fk)` ... what do you mean with that. I would assume FK constraint violated. I think your tests are working cause the test_db is recreated everytime you start your tests (assuming that you are not using --keep-db in your TestConfig)

Comment: This is the full error that was thrown:

insert or update on table "notifications_reportnotification_reports" violates foreign key constraint "notifications_report_reportnotification_i_e4e9e1e1_fk_notificat"
DETAIL:  Key (reportnotification_id)=(c77f242f-e3fd-42ad-8418-2ec47b0256b0) is not present in table "notifications_reportnotification".

Comment: -keepdb is just keeping the schema, not the data, isn't that correct?

Comment: There are entries missing in table `notifications_reportnotification`. I would suspect the entries in `reports_list`. You should check them. --keepdb is keeping the schema. You are right. The data is deleted after each run